# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied when running python file using subprocess

Tags: python, tkinter

Im making an IDE in tkinter, and Ive gotten the program to open a file and also a function to run the file, I can run stuff like `print("Hello World")`, but when I try to run tkinter scripts or even something as simple as `input()`, it either freezes or gives me `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied <path>`.

The path is /home/user/Desktop/code.py

```
import os
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
from tkinter import filedialog
import subprocess

filename = ""

def savefile():
        global filename
        if filename == "":
                filename = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialdir = "/", title = "Save File", defaultextension=".py")
        writefile = open(filename, "w")
        writefile.write(input.get("1.0", END))

def openfile():
        global filename
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/", title = "Open File", filetypes = (("Python Files", "*.py"), ("All Files", "*.*")))
        readfile = open(filename, "r")
        input.delete(1.0, END)
        input.insert(1.0, readfile.read())

def runfile():
        global filename
        savefile()
        print (filename)
        cmd = f"sudo python3 {filename}"
        process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        output, error =  process.communicate()
        outputshell.delete(1.0, END)
        outputshell.insert(1.0, output)
        outputshell.insert(1.0, error)

root = Tk()
root.title("PYIDE")
screenwidth = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screenheight = root.winfo_screenheight()
root.geometry(f"{screenwidth}x{screenheight}")

input = Text(root, wrap=None)
input.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
input.focus()

outputshell = ScrolledText(root, height=10)
outputshell.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

root.mainloop()
```

It only works when I run the program as root, even though its only my desktop. Is there any way I dont need to be root?

Apologies if I didn't provide enough code I tried to get as little as need, thanks for any help

Full error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/jayden/Desktop/workspace/pyide.py", line 22, in runfile
    savefile()
  File "/home/jayden/Desktop/workspace/pyide.py", line 35, in savefile
    writefile = open(filename, "w")
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/jayden/Desktop/smashnotes.py'
```

Comment: Why do you use `sudo`?

Comment: In ```cmd = f"sudo python3 {filename}"``` I tried using it in an attempt to fix the permission error

Comment: `sudo` requires user to input the password, but your code does not provide it.  It is not recommended to use `sudo` due to security.

Comment: @acw1668 I removed sudo and nothing changes

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: do you have this problem when you run directly `python3 /home/user/Desktop/code.py` ?

Comment: you didn't show full error message but maybe problem makes `savefile()`. Where do you save new file? Maybe it tries to save in folder which need privileges.

Comment: if you run with `shell=True` then subprocess should need list `cmd = ["python3", filename]`, If you use single string then it may treat full string as long, single name of file - and it may have problem to find it.

Comment: I get this error when I try to save file in wrong folder - ie. in system main folder `/code.py`

Comment: @furas sorry for the late answers: i added the error message; I run ```python3 code.py``` inside the project folder; ```savefile()``` asks the user for a path then saves it there; I can run helloworld and stuff fine, just anything else freezes

Comment: The error is on `savefile()` and it is nothing related to `subprocess`. Also no code on `savefile()`.

Comment: @acw1668 I added the ```savefile()``` code and read through the full error but i still dont understand what is the problem

Comment: What is the owner and the file attributes of the problem file `smashnotes.py`?

Comment: I own the file what do you mean by attributes? its just a regular .py file

Comment: error only confirm that problem is to save file. Files and folders may have privileges to read/write/execute for user(owner), group or others - if setting are wrong then it can make problem. Sometimes problem can be if file is already opened by other process and then system may block writing. You forgot to close file after saving and maybe this make problem.

Comment: @furas I did forget to add a ```writefile.close()``` but I still get the error

Comment: File attributes are those `rw-rw-r--` shown on `ls -l`.  Post the output of `ls -l smashnotes.py`.

Comment: ps. sometimes problem can make folder privileges. It can have privileges for reading files but not for writing. Or maybe command `lsof` (`list open files`) could help to check if other program use this file.

Comment: @acw1668 @furas it would seem that smashnotes.py was owned by root without me knowing, but also do you have any idea why it freezes when I try to run ```print(input())```?

Comment: Where is `print(input())` in your code?  Note that `input()` is a python built-in console input function, better not using it as any variable name.

Comment: @acw1668 sorry i should've worded this better i haven't done this sorta stuff in a while. Its an IDE as you might have guessed, the first problem was when I tried to run a file as root in the IDE, the second problem was when I run the code ```print(input())``` inside the project, it just freezes and I cant do anything except force close the window.

Comment: As I said `input()` is a console input function which *waits for user to input something*. That is why it freezes.  What do you want to do on `print(input())`?

Comment: I just want to be able to do ```input()``` in the programs console area, but when I try to do that I cant input anything into said console and the whole program freezes.

Answer (score -2):

Please don't use `sudo`. Is `/home/jayden/Desktop/smashnotes.py` readable in the first place? Who owns it and who's running the code?

Comment: ```smashnote.py``` runs fine when i run it in console. I removed the sudo from the code and it still has the same error

Comment: I figured that probably wasn't the reason, but just for the sake of covering the basics, can you run `ls -lA /home/jayden/Desktop/` and post the relevant lines?

Comment: what would be considered relevant? Just the program im trying to run?

Comment: at least the `/home/jayden/Desktop/smashnotes.py` line please.

Comment: ```-rw-r--r--  1 root   root   190 Mar  2 11:51  smashnotes.py``` I see that its owned by root is this the problem?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly your problem. Try `chown YOURUSERNAME:YOURUSERNAME smashnotes.py`

Comment: You need to use `sudo chown ...` if the file is not own by you.